# @Converter does not work with JPA 2.4

Tags: java, mysql, jpa-2.0, jodatime

I'm having trouble getting @Converter in JPA 2.4 to work. I've followed examples at [here](http://hantsy.blogspot.com/2013/12/jpa-21-attribute-converter.html) and [here](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/). When I try to persist my Entity, it fails with the following exception. Has anyone has success doing this successfully? Is there anything I should be paying attention to?

> Causing: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x16org.joda.time.DateTime\xB8

**Converter Class**

```
@Converter
public class DateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<DateTime, Timestamp> {
    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(DateTime dateTime) {
        return new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis());
    }

    @Override
    public DateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp date) {
        return new DateTime(date);
    }
}
```

**And the usage looks like**

```
@Column(name = "created_on")
@Convert(converter = CustomConverter.class)
private DateTime createdOn;
```

Answer (score 0):

There a several wrong things here:

1. The exception you got suggests that the current value contained in the column is a serialized org.joda.time.DateTime.
2. The type of the field should be the return type of the `convertToEntityAttribute` method of your converter so in your case `DateTime` not `Date`

Comment: @ks_ Apologies. I was trying out several things and what I posted was incorrect. The return type in my Entity is joda.DateTime. I've corrected it in the question.

Comment: So reset the schema to adress problem 1 and it should be fine.

Comment: Reset the schema? I was trying to hit a breakpoint in one of my converter methods and I see that we never get to the Converter class at all. Could I be missing any other wiring?

Comment: You have invalid data in your database in your column `createdOn`. Most likely you started jpa without the typeconverter, that creates a binary column and inserts the data as serialized objects. Delete the column and let jpa recreate it, or delete the whole database to reset the schema.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. If I'm not hitting the code that does the actual conversion, it could hardly be a schema issue. The problem is the data application is trying to push, not when DB persists it. In any case, I started my server to give JPA to do it's stuff and then recreated the schema. Same error.